# Recordet.update in PHP

Tags: php, recordset

I am developing an application in PHP. I m basically a ASP programmer. In ASP we update a record using recordset.update command. 
Is this possible in PHP.

my requirement is to update individual field of a record not all the fields in one statement.

Example in ASP with SQLserver as database

```
set rs=server.createobject("adodb.recordset")

loop through individual fields of the records or table
for i=0 to fields.count-1
{
       get data for each field from web form
       rs(i)=fields.name
       rs.update 
}
```

is the above code is possible in PHP using MYSQL.

Comment: you should go through the docs first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using core PHP or any framework? if you are using core PHP then the answer is that, in foreach loop you will be updating the each record manually. i.e. the fields you have made changes in, you will update them via update query as you will have the Primary key of that record in foreach loop, also you will the having column names.

And if you are using any framework like YII then you just have to change the attribute values you made changes in, and call the update function like $model->update(); as you are doingin your ASP code.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot implement like this in php as it is. You have to write proper Update query for updating the records (if you are not using any framework).

Comment: I am new to PHP. and as there is no such framework in asp. I am not really aware of it. Can you let me know which framework will serve my purpose

Comment: ok, i will explain you steps only, but can you post some code here so that my answer will be as per ur requirement. like html code or php code that u have used unitl now.